Manhwa about a female lead that was betrayed by her cousin and poisoned
I remember the first chapter is it’s the female lead's wedding day. Her cousin poisons her and she goes to the altar and dies.
She’s then returned back in time though I don’t remember if it was just back to the wedding day or before that. Her parents were killed years ago and she was living with her cousin and aunt and uncle(?) and her cousin made everyone outside think she was stupid and didn’t know anything. They also wanted her to not know she had great power.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Was it in colour or black-and-white?

What time period was the story set in? Was the cousin male or female? What colour was the female lead's hair?

Hi I read it a couple years ago tho I can’t remember where but it was in color.  The cousin was a girl I think the female leads hit may have been like a purple gray or silver I can’t recall ;-;

This is The Villainess Behind the Mask.

Ever since she was a child, Winsty has hidden the fact that she’s a wizard.
Her parents warned her to wait to use her abilities because her power was too much, and when a tragedy resulted in her parents’ deaths, Winsty was convinced her use of magic was the reason. Vulnerable and weak, her cousin Adelina supports her throughout her life, often “exerting” herself as the “head” of the family in Winsty’s stead.
So, when Winsty is poisoned on her wedding day by her cousin, the shock is enormous. But something brings Winsty back to the moment just before the wedding. To enact her revenge and take back what is hers, she will enter into a contractual relationship with a duke from a rival family. Her journey to take down Adelina and bring honor back to her family also reveals a conspiracy that goes all the way to the emperor.



@BriannaLew - No problemo :-)
